# Get UUID, Major and Minor values with Bluez

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibeacon, bluez

With Bluez I was able to get the MAC adresses of beacons with this command

> sudo hcitool lescan

But this return MAC adresses and not the detected UUID, Major and Minor values.Did someone have an idea how to get them ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the raw output of the advertisement as bytes with the `hcidump` command, then parse the beacon identifiers out of these bytes.  Here is a script that does exactly that for the open source AltBeacon format:

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/altbeacon-reference/blob/master/altbeacon_receive

If you want to do the equivalent for iBeacon, you must modify the parsing script to handle that similar format.  Because the iBeacon format is proprietary, posting the AltBeacon version is the best I can do to help.